# PHP user permissions for navigation table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my database, one called `admin` which contains users and another called `admin_permissions` which contain the pages for the site and what users will have permission.

both tables have columns:

```
admin
technical_support
sales
accounts
```

these columns are either `blank` or `Y`

for example, if a user in the admin table has a `Y` in the admin column it means they are a member of the admin user type, then i want to be able to check the `admin_permissions` table to see if the user role has access to the page

and i need to do this for each user type.

i thought of first creating an array as below for each user type:

```
$user_types = array('admin' => 'admin', 'technical_support' => 'technical_support', 'accounts' => 'accounts', 'sales' => 'sales');
```

then looping through this array after i have selected the page from the `admin_permissions` table and seeing if the user is part of the correct access group like this:

```
foreach($user_types as $perm_role => $user_role) {
    if($result[$perm_role] == $InternalUserResult[$user_role]) {

    }

}

$InternalUserResult is the objects returned from a query when selecting the current logged in user
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but why bother wasting your time here?!

Comment: Because there's a difference between "I have problem X, I've tried Y, and Z happened" and "I have problem X, fix it for me".  We're here to HELP, not do your job for you. That means "show what you've tried so far".

Comment: Does a user have to have ALL the permissions for the page, or just match one of them? E.g. if a page has `admin = Y, sales=Y`, does the user have to be a member of both admin and sales groups?

Comment: if the page has sales = Y then the user must have sales = Y but if the page has sales = Y AND admin = Y, then as long as the user has either sales OR admin then they can access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will tell you if a user has any of the required permissions for a page:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as permission
FROM admin AS a
JOIN admin_permissions AS p 
ON ((a.admin = 'y' AND p.admin = 'y')
    OR (a.technical_support = 'y' AND p.technical_support = 'y')
    OR (a.sales = 'y' AND p.sales = 'y' 
    OR (a.accounts = 'y' AND p.accounts = 'y'))
WHERE a.username = :user
AND p.page = :page
```

`permission` will be `1` if they have permission, `0` otherwise.

Instead of having separate columns for each permission type, it would be better to have a table that lists all the roles that a user has, and the groups that have access to a page. This way, if you add more groups, you don't need to modify the tables and all the queries that check it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 1 as permission
FROM user_groups AS u
JOIN page_permissions AS p ON u.type = p.type
WHERE u.username = :user
AND p.page = :page
```

Comment: using your second option, how would the table structure be? I'm not sure i 100% understand

Comment: `user_groups` has columns `username` and `type`, with one row for each group that the user is in. `page_permissions` has columns `page` and `type`, with one row for each group that has access to the page.

Comment: how about if a page in the page_permissions table needs two user groups?

Comment: It will have two rows. Like I said, one row for each group that has access to the page. This is a standard many-to-many relationship table.

Comment: so if the page has two groups that have access to it, there will need to be two rows in the page permissions table?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said. And if a user is a member of two groups, he will have two rows in the `user_groups` table.